# How to use laravel collection helper methods?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-collection

I'm trying to build a small application on `laravel-5.4` where I'm having a relational query something like this:

```
$companies = Company::where('is_client', '=', 1)
    // load count on distant model
    ->with(['interactionSummaries.interaction' => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount(['contactsAssociation' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('company', function ($q) {
                $q->where('type', 'like', 'Investor');
            });
        }]);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Now I want to collect all the `contact_association_counts` generated from the query and add it to individual company collection For this I'm using `pluck`, `collapse` and `sum` method, but I don't know it is not calculating as desired. Following is the screenshots:

I get list of collection as following:

[image: list of company]

Now I get the attributes:

[image: Attributes]

Now relational data:

[image: relational data]

Now interaction data, where the count belongs:

[image: Interaction data]

So for this I tried:

```
$companies = Company::where('is_client', '=', 1)
    // load count on distant model
    ->with(['interactionSummaries.interaction' => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount(['contactsAssociation' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('company', function ($q) {
                $q->where('type', 'like', 'Investor');
            });
        }]);
    }])
    ->get()
    ->transform(function ($company) {
        $company->contacts_association_count = $company->interactionSummaries
            ->pluck('interaction.contacts_association_count')
            ->collapse()
            ->sum();
        return $company;
    });
```

But this is not calculating the counts, all the counts are coming to 0

Help me out in this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problem is the `->collapse()` seeing your example after the `->pluck('interaction.contacts_association_count')` you should have a flat array as `[1,2,3,4,5]` if you apply `collapse()` to a flat array it returns a void array `[]` and the sum of a void array is 0

```
$companies = Company::where('is_client', '=', 1)
    // load count on distant model
    ->with(['interactionSummaries.interaction' => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount(['contactsAssociation' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('company', function ($q) {
                $q->where('type', 'like', 'Investor');
            });
        }]);
    }])
    ->get()
    ->transform(function ($company) {
        $company->contacts_association_count = $company->interactionSummaries
            ->pluck('interaction.contacts_association_count')
            //->collapse()
            ->sum();
        return $company;
    });
```

I hope it works... good luck!